# await returns before task completes

Tags: c#, asynchronous, lambda, async-await, task

I have this async code

```
private async Task<InvalidInvoiceViewModel> ValidateInsertedDataInRawTables(string uploadPath, long batchId)
    {
        var direcotryPath = Path.Combine(uploadPath, batchId.ToString());
        var allFiles = Directory.GetFiles(direcotryPath);
        var invoiceRawList = new List<InvoiceRaw>();
        var invoiceDetailRawList = new List<InvoiceDetailRaw>();
        await Task.Run(() => allFiles.ToList().ForEach(async file => 
        {
            var fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);
            switch (fileName)
            {
                case "invoice":
                    invoiceRawList = await ValidateInsertedDataInRawTablesForInvoiceAsync(batchId);
                    break;
                case "invoicedetails":
                    invoiceDetailRawList = await ValidateInsertedDataInRawTablesForInvoiceDetailAsync(batchId);
                    break;
            }
        }));
        var invalidInvoiceViewModel = new InvalidInvoiceViewModel
        {
            InvoiceRawList = invoiceRawList ,
            InvoiceDetailRawList = invoiceDetailRawList 
        };
        return invalidInvoiceViewModel;
    }
```

But what happens is, the I always get 0 count in both the `InvoiceRawList` and `InvoiceDetailRawList`. What I found is that the method returns *before* the async lambda completes its processing. (In chrome console, the result appears in the network tab, but the debug point in `ValidateInsertedDataInRawTablesForInvoiceAsync` is hit after that). I am awaiting the `Task.Run` that I created for this lambda. What am I doing wrong here?

**Update after comments**

If I do that, it won't compile, I changed it to...

```
private async Task<InvalidInvoiceViewModel> ValidateInsertedDataInRawTables(string uploadPath, long batchId)
    {
        var direcotryPath = Path.Combine(uploadPath, batchId.ToString());
        var allFiles = Directory.GetFiles(direcotryPath);
        var invoiceRawList = new List<InvoiceRaw>();
        var invoiceDetailRawList = new List<InvoiceDetailRaw>();
        await Task.Run(async () => await allFiles.ToList().ForEach(async file => 
        {
            var fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);
            switch (fileName)
            {
                case "invoice":
                    invoiceRawList = await ValidateInsertedDataInRawTablesForInvoiceAsync(batchId);
                    break;
                case "invoicedetails":
                    invoiceDetailRawList = await ValidateInsertedDataInRawTablesForInvoiceDetailAsync(batchId);
                    break;
            }
        }));
        var invalidInvoiceViewModel = new InvalidInvoiceViewModel
        {
            InvoiceRawList = invoiceRawList ,
            InvoiceDetailRawList = invoiceDetailRawList 
        };
        return invalidInvoiceViewModel;
    }
```

And says cannot await void. Which I know what that means, but then how do I resolve that? List.ForEach is a void method.

Comment: You are not awaiting your ForEach loop body, which is also async.

Comment: And **each** file set the invoiceRawList and invoiceDetailRawList

Comment: @Evk: I did that, but now it won't even compile!

Comment: Of course it does not compile. ForEach is a **void** method you cannot await at all

Comment: You might consider using await for this. It will be an await jungle...

Comment: @SirRufo: Yeah I get that. But can you help me sort out that then how should I do this?

Comment: Well not this way. Either replace with regular foreach, or put all tasks into a list and await all of them with await Task.WhenAll.

Comment: @Downvoter: If you are down-voting, at least please comment so that I know what I need to improve next time I post a question!

Answer (score 2):

You actually want to wait for WHEN ALL of the inner tasks are finished.

`Task.WhenAll` is your friend in this case.

```
private async Task<InvalidInvoiceViewModel> ValidateInsertedDataInRawTables(string uploadPath, long batchId)
{
    var direcotryPath = Path.Combine(uploadPath, batchId.ToString());
    var allFiles = Directory.GetFiles(direcotryPath);
    var invoiceRawList = new List<InvoiceRaw>();
    var invoiceDetailRawList = new List<InvoiceDetailRaw>();

    List<Task> tasks = allFiles.Select(file => Task.Run(async () =>     
    {
        var fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);
        switch (fileName)
        {
            case "invoice":
                invoiceRawList = await ValidateInsertedDataInRawTablesForInvoiceAsync(batchId);
                break;
            case "invoicedetails":
                invoiceDetailRawList = await ValidateInsertedDataInRawTablesForInvoiceDetailAsync(batchId);
                break;
        }
    })).ToList();

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

    var invalidInvoiceViewModel = new InvalidInvoiceViewModel
    {
        InvoiceRawList = invoiceRawList,
        InvoiceDetailRawList = invoiceDetailRawList
    };
    return invalidInvoiceViewModel;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use regular foreach loop if you want to use await inside it.

```
    private async Task<InvalidInvoiceViewModel> ValidateInsertedDataInRawTables(string uploadPath, long batchId)
    {
        var direcotryPath = Path.Combine(uploadPath, batchId.ToString());
        var allFiles = Directory.GetFiles(direcotryPath);
        var invoiceRawList = new List<InvoiceRaw>();
        var invoiceDetailRawList = new List<InvoiceDetailRaw>();
        await Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            foreach(var file in allFiles)
            {
                var fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);
                switch (fileName)
                {
                    case "invoice":
                        invoiceRawList = await ValidateInsertedDataInRawTablesForInvoiceAsync(batchId);
                        break;
                    case "invoicedetails":
                        invoiceDetailRawList = await ValidateInsertedDataInRawTablesForInvoiceDetailAsync(batchId);
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
        var invalidInvoiceViewModel = new InvalidInvoiceViewModel
        {
            InvoiceRawList = invoiceRawList,
            InvoiceDetailRawList = invoiceDetailRawList
        };
        return invalidInvoiceViewModel;
    }
```

By the way, this code does not make much sense, you are creating `invoiceRawList` and `invoiceDetailRawList` just to replace them in every iteration of the loop.

Comment: I know, but we will only always have 2 files, `invoice` and `invoicedetails` in each folder.

Comment: Then rewrite your code that it is a fact and not a lucky shot

Comment: How do the Validate... methods know the file to process? You just pass the batchId to them. Seems to be very fragile structure

Comment: @SirRufo: Actually they are 2 different methods, one for the `invoice` file `ValidateInsertedDataInRawTablesForInvoiceAsync` and the other for the `invoicedetail` file `ValidateInsertedDataInRawTablesForInvoiceDetailAsync`. Do you still think it's a problem?

Comment: How do these methods know the uploadPath?

Comment: @SirRufo: They don't need to. These methods call a `SQL Stored Procedure` that takes in the current `batchId` and then validates the inserted data of the current batch (of the `batchId` passed).

Comment: I see, you already processed the files ... then I would not rely on asking the filesystem, instead pass an enum